# Test If Version update works fine

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

Some days back i had few problems regarding the version updates from iOS 4.0 to 6.0 . The entire database was cleaned when the new version was installed .

Is there any way I can test version update before submitting to apple ?

I tested version updates via

1. Hockey
2. AdHoc build installed via iPhone configuration utility.

Is there any other way i can test the things so i can be sure that the update will not have any problems?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On a fresh phone (or a phone that does not have your app on it), download the current version of the app from the App Store.  Setup all the necessary data, create values in your database, etc.  Then update your app in the phone via adhoc release or [TestFlight](https://www.testflightapp.com/).  The key point is to have the most up-to-date public version of your app first.

Answer (score 14):

You can test it via [TestFlight](https://www.testflightapp.com/) service.  It's a great tool and I use it often to test my updates.

Answer (score 5):

Try out [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/). It provides instant and detailed crash reports, right down the line # at which a problem occurred.

It negligible in size (a few hundred KB), but even works on release distributions! That means even if you miss a few bugs, you will be notified instantly the moment a crash occurs, rather than having to wait for the useless Apple Crash Reports to be published.

Hope that helps you out a bit.